# When is Using Flashrom on Laptops Dangerous?

Tags: laptop, bios, flashing

Background: I want to recover a Netbook (Lenovo Ideapad 100S 11IBY) that has been bricked by losing power during what seemed to be an unexpected BIOS update.<sup>1)</sup> After some reading, I got a new BIOS file from the Lenovo Support page, bought a cheap ch341a programmer to be clamped to the BIOS chip, and how want to use `flashrom` to install the BIOS from a second computer (mine, running Linux).

Now the actual question: Both the `flashrom` man page and the [website](https://flashrom.org/Laptops) stress that using `flashrom` on a laptop is dangerous. From the man page:

> Using flashrom on laptops is dangerous and may easily make your hardware  unusable.  flashrom  will  attempt to detect if it is running on a laptop and abort immediately for  safety  reasons.

The way I understand the further explanation -- but I could not find this explicitly confirmed anywhere -- is that this is only when using the `internal` programmer, i.e. when using a laptop computer to flash the BIOS on *the same* computer while it is running, but *not* when flashing another BIOS chip connected to the laptop computer. Is this correct?

- Is using `flashrom` dangerous when used on a laptop to flash the BIOS of *another* computer using an external programmer?
- Is using `flashrom` dangerous when flashing the BIOS of a laptop computer *from* another computer?
- And possibly more general: Can `flashrom` cause any harm to the host computer when *not* using the `internal` programmer?

---

<sup>1)</sup> A BIOS update should not happen unexpected, but that's the only explanation I have. During boot, the laptop (not mine) wanted to perform some update (did not look Windows-related) and then lost power and could not boot again, not even power up the screen or enter BIOS. This is not related to the actual question, but if you have any ideas here, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flashrom` itself won't cause any harm to the host, but improper wiring or mismatching voltages can do real damage.

You can always use RPI as the external flasher to stay on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good and important point to consider. The board in question is indeed very small and the bios chip is impossible to remove and tricky to clamp on to. Will wait with accepting though for a more definite answer to the actual question, though.